# "@Produces"ed user null on @Inject in Filter because initialized before logging in

Tags: java, authentication, filter, cdi, inject

I'm trying to inject a User which should be initialized after a login process, via `@Produces`. However, after a successful login, the user injected remains `null` in my `Filter` called `AuthFilter`...

All the login process occurs in `LoginBean`.

Below is my code :

**My LoginBean :**

```
@SessionScoped
@Model
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    @Inject Credentials credentials;
    private @EJB UserService das;

    private User currentUser;

    public static final String LOGIN_LINK = "/login.xhtml";

    public String login() {
        User nonAuthUser = das.findUser(credentials); // "findUser" returns null if no user found in database;
                                                      // otherwise, returns the User

        if(nonAuthUser!=null){
            currentUser = nonAuthUser;
            return urlRedirection;

        } else {
            // ...
            // INFORMING THE FORM SUBMITTER THAT THE LOGIN/PASSWORD
            // ARE INCORRECT
            // ...

            return null;
        }
    }

    public String logout() {
        currentUser = null;
        return LOGIN_LINK;
    }

    public UserService getDas() {
        return das;
    }

    @Produces @LoggedIn User getcurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }
}
```

**Credentials class :**

```
@Model
public class Credentials{
    private String login;
    private String password;

    // ...    
    // HERE IS PART OF CODE FOR THE GETTERS + SETTERS
    // ...
}
```

**User class :**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String login;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    // ...    
    // HERE IS PART OF CODE FOR THE GETTERS + SETTERS
    // ...
}
```

**LoggedIn interface :**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface LoggedIn {}
```

**My Filter :**

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "AuthFilter", urlPatterns = {"*.xhtml"})
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    @Inject @LoggedIn User currentUser;

    public AuthFilter() {}

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        boolean isLoggedIn = currentUser != null;

        // ...
        // HERE IS A PART OF CODE WHICH WILL REDIRECT THE USER:
        //   - TO THE LOGIN PAGE IF HE'S NOT LOGGED IN
        //   - TO THE REQUESTED IN THE CONTRARY CASE
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

The problem is that the variable `isLoggedIn` initialized from the method `Authfilter.doFilter` above always returns `false`.

After doing some debugging, I've realized that's because the producer (in the `LoginBean`) is called before the user even submits the login form, initializing the `currentUser` to `null` on the 1st place.

What I'd like is to "produce" the `currentUser` after login in, and not before.

Thanks for all the suggestions to solve this problem.

(Note: I want to work in full CDI)

Comment: Have you tried injecting the `LoginBean` into Filter and retrieving the user from there? The possible problem might be in the fact that your producer produces `@Dependent` scope.  That might mean you inject it once (as `null`) and it just stays there for ever. If you operate on session scope, it should work as you expect to.

Comment: @Siliarus : Thanks for you reply. When injected into `Filter`, the `LoginBean` is also null :(...

Comment: Can you verify that the producer works? E.g. can you inject the user somewhere else, or can you do something like `CDI.current().select(User.class).get()` (static call to retrieve instances) from wherever you know the user won't be null anymore? Have you debugged the producer (when does it get called, how many times)?

Comment: Oh and what environment are we talking about? Full EE server such as WildFly? Or just servlets?